# Triple For loop in python, major confusion

Tags: python-2.7, loops, for-loop, iteration

```
for i in range(4):
        for j in V[i].customers:
            V[i].message =\
                            dict([(k,array([1,1])) \
                                 for k in V[i]. customers])
```

I dont understand this for structure at all. Could some one explain how this works ?

Also, that `=\` what does it do?

Comment: lol, if only I had a dollar for every time someone posted here a bad written code and asked us to explain it... the \ was added in order to be able to continue to write the rest of the code on a newline

Comment: That isn't a triple loop.  Are you missing some code?

Comment: @mrogers indeed, i corrected this now

Comment: @alfasin hehe, many people are new to python!

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah i know that. The last for , this is what i cannot understand how it itterates over the other two for loops.

Comment: @MartijnPieters actually, i didnt know that, very interesting. Still i dont get the last for how it works.

Comment: @Xptrz: it doesn't. It's a list comprehension producing key-value pairs in a dictionary.  And I misread, it's not a `\=` augmented assignment, it's a straight assignment with ``\`` escape character to extend the line.

Comment: The last for is not a loop but a list comprehension. I totally get why you would be confused about the code; it is horrible. The `j` isn't even used at all?

Comment: @jmd_dk Whoa, that is true, i don't see a j either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line is somewhat confusing to read because the author choose to use `\` *line-continuation escapes*. The line is easier read without those:

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in V[i].customers:
        V[i].message = dict((k, array([1,1])) for k in V[i].customers)
```

I also removed the list comprehension, the code is faster without it. The loop in the `dict()` call is now a *generator expression*, and it produces `(key, value)` tuple pairs for `dict()` to turn into a dictionary.

So for 4 different `V[i].customers` sequences, the corresponding `V[i].message` attribute is repeatedly set to the same dictionary. This is rather useless, as `j` isn't even used, so the `for j` loop could just be removed:

```
for i in range(4):
    V[i].message = dict((k, array([1,1])) for k in V[i].customers)
```

Next, if `V` only *has* four indices, you could replace the `range()` with a loop directly over `V`:

```
for v in V:
    v.message = dict((k, array([1,1])) for k in v.customers)
```

and if this code is designed to run on Python 2.7 or newer (so if Python 2.6 compatibility is not a requirement), you could replace the latter with a *dictionary comprehension*:

```
for v in V:
    v.message = {k: array([1,1]) for k in v.customers}
```